# (react-route) Nested route shows a 404 not found when visiting the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and react-route and I was following the documentation on how to use nested routes to use on the project that I am currently doing below is my code:

[App.js file]

```
         <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Index />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/counsellor">
                    <Counsellor />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </Router>
```

[Counsellor.js file]

```
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

return (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
            <Index />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/profile`}>
            <div>Test</div>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
);
```

The " path={path} " works fine but the " path={`${path}/profile`} " shows a 404 Not Found.

P.S. The project that I'm building is using Laravel, React.js, Material React, and some other things, and I'm still learning all of these things along the way.

Comment: Are you using <Link> to navigate to the nested route (`path={\`${path}/profile\`}`)?

Comment: No, I'm not using a link to navigate to the nested route.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason why